# Java Example With Cxf

Tags: java, client, cxf

I want to run the following web service.I will give two parameters and this web service simply
returns these parameters back to me.
http://soapclient.com/xml/soapresponder.wsdl
I want to generate a client program using this service (create client with apache-cxf), two text box,
sending parameters and a result textbox, showing the response. Problem is i dont know how doing these things on java.Before i interested on .Net c#. I want to develop myself but no more documents on this topic in my own country.

Comment: What is the question? Are you asking for a link to CXF examples? http://cxf.apache.org/docs/sample-projects.html

Comment: let i explain clearly.No not link. I am new about java and apache cxf and i don't know how doing this things in java.I want to write simple example project that uses link http://soapclient.com/xml/soapresponder.wsdl exixts on the internet.

Comment: @samlewis sorry i wrote wrong i tried to write exists

Comment: You already have a wsdl so you can look at the 'wsdl first' examples.

Comment: i am starting to look wsdl first examples then.Ok i will listen your advice.Thanks :)